# OBDII bluetooth-reader iOS app on Github?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, obd-ii

I am currently working on a iOS project that can connect with a OBDII dongle via bluetooth. Does anyone know any github projects I can study from? It seems that there are not many resources for iOS development on OBD.

Comment: Requesting outside resources like this isn't really in the scope of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to search query as below on github to get OBD2 result for ios and iphone.

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=obd2+ios

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=obd2+iphone&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

I hope its helps you.